# Round all datetime record at given conditions

Tags: sql, datetime, rounding

I have a table (timbrature) containing a lot of datetime record for users, I would round only the field with value between 23:31 and 23:59 to 00:00 of the next day.
I came up with this query with the help of the net:

datao is the datetime field
iddip it's the id of the relative user

```
declare @dt datetime
set @dt = (select DATAO from timbrature where IDDIP=11)
update timbrature set datao= (select dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, dateadd(mi, 30, @dt)), 0)) where IDDIP=11
```

The query work as expected regarding the rounding part (in the example I omitted the where clause checking the time range), but how can I loop through all the records? Thanks

Comment: Remove the second `WHERE IDDIP = 11` and it will update the entire table

Comment: That is non-standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the temp var, just use datepart in your where clause and get time directly from DATAO column.

```
declare @timbrature table (DATAO datetime, IDDIP int)
insert into @timbrature
select '2017-01-01 04:00:00.000',1 union
select '2017-01-01 23:30:00.000',2 union
select '2017-01-01 23:31:00.000',3 union
select '2017-01-01 23:59:00.000',4 union
select '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000',5

update @timbrature 
set DATAO= dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, dateadd(mi, 30, DATAO)), 0) 
from @timbrature 
where datepart(hour,DATAO)=23 and datepart(minute,DATAO)>30

select * from @timbrature order by IDDIP
```

The result will be

```
DATAO                   IDDIP
----------------------- -----------
2017-01-01 04:00:00.000 1
2017-01-01 23:30:00.000 2
2017-01-02 00:00:00.000 3
2017-01-02 00:00:00.000 4
2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 5
```